# Jquery Fancybox 3 download not working but opening file

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I am tying to use fancybox download file functionality and it is working fine locally but not on production system

```js
$(".fancybox-gallary").fancybox({
      closeExisting: false,
      keyboard    : true,
      loop        : true,
      gutter: 50,
      margin : [44,0,22,0],
      buttons: [
        "zoom",
        "fullScreen",
        "download",
        "thumbs",
        "close"
      ],
      thumbs: { autoStart: true, hideOnClose: true, axis: 'x'}
    });
```

```css
.img_grid {
  margin: 0 -17px 1em;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  clear: both;
  zoom: 1;
}

.img_grid:before, .img_grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.img_grid:after {
  clear: both;
}

.img_grid > li {
  float: left;
  width: 208px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 17px 15px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.img_grid > li > a {
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<ul class="img_grid search_illustrations">
            <li class="row-leader">
                <a class="fancybox-gallary" data-fancybox="images" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-caption="" href="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1471/client_1REDORB.JPG">
                  <div class="img_wrapper">
                    <img src="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1471/client_thumb_1REDORB.JPG" data-original="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1471/client_thumb_1REDORB.JPG" alt="" width="208" height="208">
                    
                  </div>
</a>            </li>
           
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-gallary" data-fancybox="images" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-caption="" href="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1470/client_17.jpg">
                  <div class="img_wrapper">
                    <img src="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1470/client_thumb_17.jpg" data-original="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1470/client_thumb_17.jpg" alt="" width="208" height="208">
                    
                  </div>
</a>            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-gallary" data-fancybox="images" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-caption="" href="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1462/client_Copy_of_Copy_of_Handshake_-_Hand_holding_on_black_background_0.jpg">
                  <div class="img_wrapper">
                    <img src="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1462/client_thumb_Copy_of_Copy_of_Handshake_-_Hand_holding_on_black_background_0.jpg" data-original="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1462/client_thumb_Copy_of_Copy_of_Handshake_-_Hand_holding_on_black_background_0.jpg" alt="" width="208" height="208">
                    
                  </div>
</a>            </li>
            <li class="row-leader">
                <a class="fancybox-gallary" data-fancybox="images" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-caption="" href="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1469/client_1oxygenwall1.jpg">
                  <div class="img_wrapper">
                    <img src="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1469/client_thumb_1oxygenwall1.jpg" data-original="https://beehiveillustration--staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/artwork/image/1469/client_thumb_1oxygenwall1.jpg" alt="" width="208" height="208">
                    
                  </div>
</a>            </li>
            
        </ul>
```

But this opens file instead of download. Can anyone suggest how to make it to download file. Also I want to customise download file as i want to allow only low resolution file to be downloadable

Answer (score 0):

The script uses HTML5 `download` attribute for download link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes The rest is up to the browser (and you).

If you are not satisfied with default functionality, it is quite easy to create your own toolbar button, see docs for samples https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-3 Also, you can use callbacks to customize download url or to create custom click event.